# How Can I Access Referenced Schema's Specific Data With Nodejs and mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to make a comment authorization in my website. I want only to get  the comments of the post that I found by it's id. And accessing the datas of that comments.

This is my posts route.

```
Campground.findById(req.params.id).populate("comments").exec(function(err, foundCampground){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            User.findById(req.user._id, (err, user)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    Campground.findById({'foundCampground.comments._id': Comments._id}, (err, comments)=>{
                        console.log("Comments of this post "+comments);
                        Comments.find({"author.id": user.id}, function(err, comment){
                            var authID = foundCampground.author.id;
                            var userID = user.id;
                            var commentIDs = [];

                            comment.forEach(function(yorum){
                                commentIDs.push(yorum.author.id);
                            });

                            var commentID = commentIDs[0];

                            console.log("alinan comments"+comment);
                            console.log("Comment Id " + commentID);
                            console.log("UserID "+userID);

                            if(userID == commentID){
                                console.log("EQUALO MORUQA");
                            }

                            res.render("campgrounds/show",{campground: foundCampground, authID: authID, userID: userID, commentID: commentID});
                        });
                    }); 
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This is my campground model

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    image: String,
    description: String,
    comments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Comment"
    }],
    author: {
        id: String,
        user: String,
    }
});
```

This is my comment model

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    author:{
        username: String,
        id: String,
    }
});
```

What should I write as query to only get the comments of foundCampground?